# how you can type complex object of object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, react-typescript

Hi I have this complex object and I need to create a type or interface for it in my react --typescript-template app

```
const columnsFromBackend = {
  ["0"]: {
    name: "Terminator Group",
    items: [
      {
        filepath: "0.jpg",
        group: "terminator",
        id: "0",
        isClicked: false,
        title: "image_0",
      },
      {
        filepath: "1.jpg",
        group: "terminator",
        id: "1",
        isClicked: false,
        title: "image_1",
      },
     ]
   }
}
```

I have tried this

```
export type Character = {
    name: string;
    items: {
      filepath: string;
      group: string;
      id: string;
      isClicked: boolean;
    }
  xxxxxxx
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState<Character{}>(columnsFromBackend);
```

but it didn't work?

Comment: @NatalieMae's answer should have you covered. But you probably also want an array of characters for you state. `useState<Character[]>`. `[]` not `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your items only as an object rather than an array of objects.

Try:

```
export type CharacterItem = {
    filepath: string;
    group: string;
    id: string;
    isClicked: boolean;
   }

export type Character = {
    name: string;
   items: CharacterItem[]
   }
```

Or something similar!

Comment: `Array<CharacterItem/>` is invalid syntax. You probably meant `Array<CharacterItem>`. Although, `CharacterItem[]` is probably more common.

Comment: I sure did! I've been playing with TSX too much! Thanks pal!

Comment: thank you, however, its still lenting red line underneath `columnsFromBackend` as in   const [columns, setColumns] = useState<Character[]>(columnsFromBackend);
with this error message
```
Argument of type '{ 0: { name: string; items: { filepath: string; group: string; id: string; isClicked: boolean; title: string; }[]; }; 1: { name: string; items: { filepath: string; group: string; id: string; isClicked: boolean; title: string; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Character[] | (() => Character[])'.ts(2345)
```